# Recommendations for an introduction to algebraic dependence and transcendence basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am just starting my studies on transcendence bases, and in particular algebraic dependence.

Are there any textbooks you would recommend? I am mainly looking to understand algebraic dependence, transcendence bases, and then the Theorem which states that if $x_1,...,x_n$ and $y_1,...,y_m$ are transcendence bases of K/k, then n=m.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Hungerford's book Algebra, pages 311-317. It has enough details and it is not too hard to read. The result you want is proved in theorem 1.8.